# Unable to publish WCF Service to hosts residing locally from BizTalk WCF Publishing Wizard

Tags: wcf, biztalk, publishing, biztalk-2010

This has been bothering me for a long time and it amazes me that I can not find anything about this online.

I have a BizTalk orchestration that I would like to expose as a WCF service. I open the BizTalk WCF Service Publishing Wizard, select Service endpoint, WCF-WSHttp and Enable metadata endpoint, I select publish BizTalk orchestration as WCF servive, then select the assembly then port, set a namespace. All this works fine, now on the WCF Service Location step, I click Browse type in a host defined in my hosts file other than local host and I get an error Host "..." is not valid. World Wide Web service (W3SVC) on host "..." not available. Access is denied.

[BTS WCF Service Deploy Error http://files.victorfeinman.com/files/Photos/BTSDeployError.png](http://files.victorfeinman.com/files/Photos/BTSDeployError.png)

I've tried a lot here, running as administrator, that doesn't do it. I've tried publishing to remote servers by hosts names I've defined in my host file - that works. I've tried publish from other machines to my local machine - that works. But I can not for the life of me publish to my local machine using any host name other than localhost.

I feel as if the lack of online content about this "issue" means it's something trivial. I hope that's the case, albeit a little embarrassing.

I running BizTalk 2010, Windows 7, Visual Studio 2010.

---

**UPDATE:** I tested a publish to a remote server with a host name services.xyz.com and even though I could browse to the site in the wizard, the wizard still placed the new application and service in the "Default Web Site" of the remote machine. Then I tried adding an additional binding with a unique port to the services.xyz.com site and tried the deployment again, this time specifying the unique port and Vola, it worked as I need it to (for a remote server). New WCF service created in the desired path based on the correct site. Great. Next thing I did then was added another binding to my local site I'm trying to publish to with a unique port, still set my host name to somehost.com. This did not change the fact that I was unable to "Browse..." using somehost.com, however, In the "Location" field, I tried putting in the unique port (like so.. `http://localhost:8080/products`) and finished the publish wizard. To my amazement this actually worked. The WCF service I wanted was created in the site and file location I wanted. Even though the target site did not have a binding for the "localhost" or empty (any) Host Name.

Comment: Did you try using 'localhost' instead of services? I don't know if windows automatically adds localhost or if it must be in the hosts file. That's the usual way to reference the local machine without hard coding a machine name into a URL

Comment: Yes, I've tried that and that "works" as in I am able to browse my local sites in IIS, however, when I try to publish to a local site other than the Default Web Site, it publishes to the default web site anyway - this is my problem. See my update for a work around.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a firewall or network issue.

When you use localhost it goes to the loopback IP address 127.0.0.1.

When you use the server name it goes to the external IP address.

Also the "." and spaces after service may be giving you some problems.

Comment: I'm sorry the actual host name has been redacted, please ignore the '.' and spaces. Also, the host name is not the server name, it is a name I assigned to the loopback IP address.